Azure Price Sheet API returning 404 error
I want to fetch the pricesheet for the Azure items on my subscription, considering any potential discounts. I understood from the API documentation, that using the billing period method would return the prices. The authentication works well, but when it hits the API after authenticating I get an error 404 back. What am I doing wrong?
API Documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/consumption/price-sheet?view=rest-consumption-2023-05-01
import requests

# Define your Azure AD and API parameters
tenant_id = 'xxx'
client_id = 'yyy'
client_secret = 'zzz'
subscriptionId = 'www'
resource = 'https://management.azure.com/'
billingPeriodName = "202407"

# OAuth2 endpoint for token retrieval
token_url = f'https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}/oauth2/v2.0/token'

# Request headers and body for token retrieval
token_data = {
    'grant_type': 'client_credentials',
    'client_id': client_id,
    'client_secret': client_secret,
    'scope': 'https://management.azure.com/.default'
}

# Get the access token
response = requests.post(token_url, data=token_data)
response.raise_for_status()
access_token = response.json().get('access_token')

# Endpoint to retrieve the current retail prices
retail_prices_url = f'https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/providers/Microsoft.Billing/billingPeriods/{billingPeriodName}/providers/Microsoft.Consumption/pricesheets/default?api-version=2023-05-01'

# Request headers for the API call
headers = {
    'Authorization': f'Bearer {access_token}',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}

# Get the current retail prices
response = requests.get(retail_prices_url, headers=headers)
response.raise_for_status()
retail_prices_data = response.json()
response.raise_for_status()  # Raise an error for bad status codes

print(token_data)
print(pricesheet_data)

Thank you!
I tried changing the API endpoints, double checked my subscription activation, allowed API access and assigned role to the app service created. Double checked tenant, client etc. IDs...

In general, 404 error comes when the requested URL was not properly passed or found on the server side. Try with the same URL given in the provided MS Doc as shown below instead of addingdefault.
Make sure that the subscription ID and billing period name details are correctly given and also check that the billing invoice profile is accessible to the user and have a necessary permission across the subscription.
I have made a few modifications to your code as shown below. Try it in your environment to achieve the expected results.
import requests
tenant_id = 'xxxx'
client_id = 'xxxxx'
client_secret = '*****'
subscriptionId = 'subscriptionId'
resource = 'https://management.azure.com/'
billingPeriodName = "xxxx"
token_url = f'https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}/oauth2/v2.0/token'
token_data = {
    'grant_type': 'client_credentials',
    'client_id': client_id,
    'client_secret': client_secret,
    'scope': 'https://management.azure.com/.default'
}

response = requests.post(token_url, data=token_data)
response.raise_for_status()
access_token = response.json().get('access_token')

retail_prices_url = f'https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/providers/Microsoft.Billing/billingPeriods/{billingPeriodName}/providers/Microsoft.Consumption/pricesheets/download?api-version=2023-05-01'

headers = {
    'Authorization': f'Bearer {access_token}',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}
response = requests.get(retail_prices_url, headers=headers)
response.raise_for_status()
retail_prices_data = response.json()
statuscode = response.status_code
if(statuscode == '404'):
    print(f'details are not obtained')
else:
    print(response.raise_for_status())
print(token_data)


